# Xcode: Breakpoints and Weird Screens

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

When I am having a problem in Xcode, I am told to debug my code with a breakpoint. Stepping through the code, you press that little arrow above the console section to go to the next line. This works fine, like when I place a breakpoint on line 150 in my code, I can then "po" a variable and find it's values.

[image]

But when I am trying to step through my code, and go from method to method, a lot of times I will be transported to this weird screen of numbers and letters and things don't make even remote sense in there. See below

[image]

Wtf does this mean, and what if anything am I supposed to do with this Klingon transition my Xcode project apparently has intercepted?

Comment: Click the "step out" icon. That's assembly (compiled) code for code you don't have the source code for.

Comment: "numbers and letters and things don't make even remote sense" They may not make sense to _you_. But there are a lot of people to whom they _do_ make sense. Don't be so quick to judge! :)

Comment: I understand. But if someone would post an answer below, perhaps I too could become a wizard of smart just like those folks.

Comment: I would look it up myself on Google and search "How to make sense of X" but I don't even know what to call this screen? What is this screen called so I can actually do research. ANYTHING?.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code you write in a language such as Objective-C or Swift is compiled into [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) for execution on a given processor - x86 for the simulator or ARM for an iOS device - In this case I would guess you are running on the simulator.

Machine code instructions perform quite discreet operations.  For example `c=a+b` would translate into something like 
    fetch a from memory
    fetch b from memory
    add a and b
    store the result into the memory for c

When you single-step through your code in the debugger, it only stops on each line of your program even though many machine code instructions may have have been executed by that step.

What you are seeing is the [assembly code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) for the framework function that has been invoked because you have "stepped into" a function that Xcode doesn't have the source to, so it has to show each low level operation.

You can use the 'step out' button to return to your code and use the 'step' rather than 'step into' button to avoid seeing this.

The line that is highlighted in your debugger is essentially checking the value of the `%al` [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) (a register is a small piece of memory in the CPU chip).  The next instruction will jump to a different part of the program if the result is that `%al` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Look on the left hand side and click on the command before the currently selected code. That will typically show you the last bit of code you wrote before the breakpoint was encountered

In the example below 0 is where the breakpoint was encountered, while 1 is last bit of code that I wrote.

[image: .]